# Apple script find and replace text

Tags: applescript

So, right now my code clicks on a textarea in safari then it adds a word using keystroke, however I was wondering if there is a way to find and replace a word in that area and also is there a way to replace a highlighted word without keystroke?

**Current code:** 
Sorry its very very poorly formatted since I am pretty bad at applescript

```
    to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" &     theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickClassName
to clickID(theId)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId &     "').click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickID   -- All the code up to this point did is allow me to click on IDs and classes in safari.

tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Safari"
        tell window 1
            set current tab to (make new tab with properties    {URL:"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?     title=User:USERNAMEHERE/sandbox&action=edit"})
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
delay 2 -- All the code up to this point from the last comment did is open a new tab in safari.
repeat 5 times
    set randomlist to {"1","2","3","4"} -- List of numbers that will be randomly selected and put in the texarea
    set randomword to some item of randomlist 
    clickClassName("tool-button wikiEditor-toolbar-spritedButton", 0) -- This clicks the bold button on the sandbox page
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            keystroke randomword -- Uses keystroke to put replace the text inside the bold formatting area 
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 1
    clickID("wpSave") -- Clicks save
    delay 2
    tell application "Safari" to set the URL of the front document to   "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?  title=User:USERNAMEHERE/sandbox&action=edit" -- Goes back to sandbox and repeats the process
    delay 2
end repeat
```

If you want to test this then put in your wikipedia username in the link and login into your account. Pretty much its a wikipedia bot that will just put stuff in my wikipedia sandbox

Comment: Can you show us your current AppleScript? You can select all text in a text field, copy it to the clipboard, modify the clipboard (replace a word) and paste the new content back to the text field in safari.

Comment: yeah but I am hoping to do it without keystroke so that I can run the script in the background

Comment: the instructions above are, what I'd do with an AppleScript. :) post your current code and we may help you.

Comment: alright one second